# $\gcd(a,b)=1,x^a=y^b\implies x=n^b, y=n^a$ for an integer $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I had this doubt in the question.
First, I took log both sides to get $a \log x=b \log y$. Since a does not divide b, a must divide log y. So log y can be written as some $\log y=am$, when we get $y= (10^m)^a$ which is of the form $y=n^a$. Is this correct or there is some flaw with the argument?

Comment: We cannot talk about divisibility if $\log y$ is not an integer.

Comment: Is it given that $x,y$ are themselves integers?

Comment: Yes they are integers

Comment: You should avoid using $\log$ in problems involving integers. The key here is that if you have numbers $a,b$ such that $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, then there exist $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ap + bq = 1$.

Comment: **Hint** $\ $ It's a multiplicative form of the following basic theorem about fractions $$aj\!+\!bk=1,\ {xa=yb}\,\Rightarrow\, \bbox[5px,border:1px solid red]{\dfrac{y}x = \dfrac{a}b\:\Rightarrow\begin{align}\,y = na\\ x = nb\end{align}}\ \ \ {\rm for\ some}\,\ n\in\Bbb Z\qquad $$

We can *mechanically* translate a proof of that into the proof you seek (see one of my answers in the linked dupe for details).